# LINQ IEnumerable and List

Tags: c#, linq

This function returns a dictionary with all key name values coming from an IEnumerable object.  I want to filter out any items that do not exist in my list that I am passing in.  I just want the properties that exist as a cols.Name

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDataRowFromObject(IEnumerable<NameValue<string, object>> properties, List<ColDefModel> cols)
    {
        var dataRow = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (NameValue<string, object> property in properties)
        {
            try
            {
                if (property.Value == null)
                    dataRow[property.Name] = "";
                else
                    dataRow[property.Name] = property.Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                dataRow[property.Name] = "";
            }
        }
        return dataRow;
    }
```

Comment: 1)You are passing a parameter you never use 2) You are probably doing a redundant try catch block but I can't be sure what your code is trying to do. 3) You are overriding values if instance with same name occur

Answer (score 2):

```
var dictionary = properties.Where(nv => nv.Value != null)
                           .Where(nv => cols.Any(c => c.ColName == nv.Name))
                           .ToDictionary(nv => nv.Name, nv => nv.Value.ToString());
```

Hopefully this shows you why your method is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, try doing your foreach through:

```
properties.Where(x => cols.Any(y => x.Name == y.Name))
```

instead of through `properties`.  If performance is an issue, try making some sort of hashed list of the names in `cols` (like a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)); say it's called `colNames`, then change the above to `x => colNames.ContainsKey(x.Name)`.